# How do you handle maintaining core updates with clients?

Tags: updating

When you develop a site using Drupal, do you include as part of it updates to core as they come out, or do you offer maintenance charges to keep it updated?

Comment: Not sure this is appropriate for SE but I will answer with it's a personal choice. I would include all maintenance as part of the hosting package -- or sell it separately should they chose to host themselves. Maintaining a complex system like Drupal is above and beyond your basic shared hosting maintenance IMO

Comment: We are currently trying to get our clients to sign some kind of update contract with us. But we are finding that most smaller clients don't really care about it. Even some larger ones are not interested. I am personally having a hard time explaining to my superiors that this is a very bad thing to do. Because you are leaving vulnerable code active on your servers and this could do more damage then the monetary losses of the time needed to update.